# phpmyadmin Hide a Column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm relatively new with programming databases and I have this simple question that  I just cannot find an answer to anywhere. I have a database with ~15 Columns, and I wanna see most of them but not all when I'm on phpmyadmin Browse window.

What I want:

1) Structurally my table consist of 15 columns

2) I want 3 columns to be hidden at all times.

3) When I browse through phpmyadmin I want to see only 12 columns because other 3 are hidden/invisible.

I tried to explain it as simple as I can.

I appreciate any help you guys can give me.
Thanks!

Comment: Just before the column names is a drop down arrow to control which columns to view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: how to hide table columns]

Open table - first row, just click on dropdown as shown in picture, then uncheck the columns you want to hide

Comment: Thank You so much! I knew it was an easy fix I just couldn't find it!

Comment: Great! If it helps you, please mark it as answered, so that it will be helpful to others